# what does "Invariant Violation : Native component for <component> does not exist means?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, sliders

[image]

I imported a third party library using " npm install --save react-native-range-slider" and getting this error! 
I can't find out where am I wrong! Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

I guest you do not link library to your app. Run **react-native link** or do this manually.

Comment: I then just removed that library and used different library instead

Comment: and it's work? Sometime you must manually link library because react-native link error.

Comment: yea!! thankyou. I just dumped that library and used another instead